# add objects in array from multiple array in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I have 2 array like as follow:

```
Array A  ( 

{ title="A",id=1 }, {title="B",id=2},{title="c",id=3}

)

Array B  ( 

{ title="A",id=1 }, {title="B",id=2},{title="c",id=3}

)
```

Now, I want to `combine this arrays` & when I try to get the values from combined array, I want know that it is from Array A or Array B.

**How can I do that?**

Should I use dictionary instead of Array?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you should use `Dictionary` instead of `Array`. Set the *Array* as an *Object* with the *Key* as *ArrayName*.

**Sample Code :**

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:arrayA,@"ArrayA",arrayB,@"ArrayB", nil];
NSLog(@"dict :: %@",dict);
```

**Update :**

To display the *title* & *id* in the `TableView` cell :

```
yourTitleLabel.text = [[[dict objectForKey:@"ArrayA"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
yourIdLabel.text = [[[dict objectForKey:@"ArrayA"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But how can I get the individual object from the array & key of that object. I want to display the title & id in the TableView cell.

Comment: @user2526811: Take a look at **Update** section in my Answer.